# Having trouble connecting to mySQL server on linux server from netbeans/java

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I am unable to connect to a MySQL server which is hosted on a linux server through netbeans.

All of these credentials work when connecting through MySQL Workbench "Standard TCP/IP through ssh".

Here is my code:

```
public class Database {
private static final String DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
private static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://john.myschool.edu:3306/cs3610";
private static final String USERNAME = "mbrooke";
private static final String PASSWORD = "mypass";
private Connection connection;

public Database() throws Exception{
    try{
        connect();
    }catch(SQLException e){
        if(connection !=null){
            connection.close();
        }
    }
}

//Open connection to database
private void connect() throws Exception{
    connection = null;
    Class.forName (DRIVER).newInstance ();
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL,USERNAME,PASSWORD);

}
```

}

I am getting SQLException with #521 on the line that starts "connection = DriverManager..." and I'm not sure what is causing this problem. The driver seems to be installed correctly as, when stepping through, I make it past the "Class.forName(D..." line with no exceptions thrown.

Comment: Some servers have built in IP control. You can discuss it with your hosting service to be sure if any IP is allowed to connect database.

Comment: I can connect to the server from MySQLWorkbench on the same computer. Would I have a different IP if it's through NetBeans?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your Database server doesn't have port 3306 open, or your MySQL credentials aren't allowed to use remote connections.

MySQL Workbench's [TCP/IP over SSH](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-manage-db-connections-ssh.html) setting first opens an SSH connection to the SSH server, then connects to the database server (often `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`). So the MySQL connection is actually initiated from the SSH server. So the ability to connect through that channel only demonstrates that your java code would work *if it were running on the server into which you're SSHing*. But you may still have a firewall or MySQL permissions issue when trying to run the code from another machine.

I would try downloading a MySQL client to your machine and seeing if you can connect using that method: `mysql -h myDatabaseServer.school.edu cs3610 -u mbrooke -p'mypass'` and see if that works. You'll likely either get a "connection not available" error or a "user mbrooke doesn't have permission to access remotely" which should give you some insight into which problem you're facing.

Answer (score 1):

Try it without ending slash

URL = "jdbc:mysql://john.myschool.edu:3306/cs3610/";

like

URL = "jdbc:mysql://john.myschool.edu:3306/cs3610";

or you have a Database named "cs3610/"